# org.json.JSONArray cannot read my JSON object

Tags: php, android, json, arrays

Im writing a client/server app for android that sends a username and password to the server and receives a status for that user account.

My php code is like this:

```
$return['login'] = 'success';   
echo json_encode($return);
```

and the text received by android is:

```
{"login":"success"}
```

but I still get an error when I try to decode the json string to read the parameters:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(input);
```

exception:

```
02-10 11:54:37.743: WARN/System.err(332): 
    org.json.JSONException: 
         Value {"login":"success"} of type org.json.JSONObject 
         cannot be converted to JSONArray
02-10 11:54:37.779: WARN/System.err(332): 
    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
```

So I guess Im missing something that php should send, but after reading on json.org I just can't see what it is. I have tried adding brackets before and after, as well as wrapping it in another array like this:

```
$parameters['login'] = 'success';   
    $return['parameters'] = $parameters;
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: probably because it is not a json array…

Comment: The exception seems obvious but I think there is a misunderstanding because PHP *Arrays* are just ordered maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [`JSONObject`](http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) instead of [`JSONArray`](http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) since you sending a key-value pair.

Comment: That explains it, in my head I was under the impression that several key-value-pairs would be an array.

Answer (score 1):

Its an `JSONObject` not an `JSONArray` so it should be,

```
JSONObject json_obj = new JSONObject(your_string);
```

Then you can just use `json_obj` to get the value,

```
String login = json_obj.getString("login");
Log.d("login status", login);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not a JSONArray, it is a JSONObject.

```
try {
    JSONObject o = new JSONObject("{\"login\":\"success\"}");
    System.out.println(o.getString("login"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
System.out  I  success
```